# Formal Language Theory - Unique "leftmost" and "rightmost" derivation tree

Tags: grammar, theory, context-free-grammar, regular-language, formal-languages

I'm studying Formal Language Theory and doing the exercises assigned to me, I found this question that I can't give a certain answer to:

> When, in general, in a context-free grammar are the leftmost and rightmost derivations of each generated string equal?
>
> - Only if the grammar generates a deterministic context-free language
> - Only if there is at most one non-terminal symbol in the right-hand
>   side of each derivation
> - Never

(P.S. : The question is translated from Italian, I hope it is understandable)

Comment: If some production has more than one non-terminal and that production is used in a derivation, then the next derivation step must differ between s leftmost derivation and a rightmost derivation. Because the only way a non-terminal can be both the leftmost and the rightmost non-terminal in a string is if it is the only non-terminal in the string.

Comment: rici got it. That said, the question is a little imprecise. Clearly, multiple non-terminals in the production only matter if those productions are reachable in the grammar. AFAIK there is no general prohibition on having useless productions in grammars.